# Iterating through a list of urls with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm attempting to iterate through a list of URLs, and instead of puppeteer loading each page, it only loads one. What can I do to make this work?

```
async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720});
  await page.goto('https://s23.a2zinc.net/clients/acmedia/americancoatingsshow2022/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?Index=All#', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // wait until page load
  const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href));

for (let i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    const url = hrefs[i];
    if (url.includes('eBooth.aspx')) {
      console.log(url)
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.goto(`${url}`);
      await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    }
}  
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is an extra `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });` that will fail to resolve. `page.goto` already waits for navigation, so you're asking Puppeteer to wait for a navigation that will never happen.

Only use `page.waitForNavigation` if you're doing something to trigger a navigation, not as part of a typical `page.goto` call. Remove this line and your code should work (more or less) as expected.

Furthermore, you're opening a whole new page (browser tab) per link. That's 360 tabs by my count, liable to run most computers out of memory. Better to navigate a single page repeatedly or close pages after you're finished doing whatever you plan to do on these pages. If that's too slow, try running chunks in parallel or using a task queue.

Also, the links are available in the static HTML, so you [might not need Puppeteer here](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-puppeteer-when-other-tools-are-more-appropriate), again, depending on what you're planning on doing on each page. If you can get all of the data from each page statically, you could have a massive speedup, completing 360 scrapes with `fetch`/`cheerio` in a fraction of the time it'd take Puppeteer.

If you do stick with Puppeteer to bypass detection or deal with JS/interactivity, [consider using `domcontentloaded`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) rather than `networkidle0`, which is usually unnecessarily strict and slow. The blog post linked explains the difference between the various loading conditions. See also my answer in the canonical thread [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded/72535642#72535642) for a deeper dive into page loading in Puppeteer.

`a[href]` is a more precise selector than `a`, because it's possible that some `a` anchors have no href and should be discarded to avoid undefineds popping up.

Here's how I'd write this (with the aforementioned caveat that Puppeteer might not be needed at all):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^14.3.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720});
  const url = "https://s23.a2zinc.net/clients/acmedia/americancoatingsshow2022/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?Index=All#";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const hrefs = await page.$$eval("a[href]", els =>
    els.map(a => a.href).filter(e => e.includes("eBooth.aspx"))
  );
  console.log(hrefs.length); // => 360

  for (const url of hrefs) {
    await page.goto(url);
    // page is loaded; do your thing on this page
  }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

<sub>Disclosure: I'm the author of the linked blog posts</sub>